# Android studio programming

Tags: android

I am developing an android application to display current news or events. But, starting the interface with the toolbar and the login page, I have a problem with ConstraintLayout. I do not know why but the textview and imageview are red while in RelativeLayout and LinearLayout it works.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.exemple.rivoramampiandra.appsname.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Connexion"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.079" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="367dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="9dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="85dp" />
```

Comment: post your code here

Comment: it said that it's too long

Comment: post xml enough.

Comment: <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="367dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="9dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="85dp" />

Comment: This part of code is not enough for us to help

Comment: Did you add appropriate dependency in `build.gradle` file. Refer https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#add-constraintlayout-to-your-project

Comment: i have already add the appropriate dependency

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your code would help a lot in solving the problem, some guesses though might be:

- Constraints were not added to the `TextView` and `ImageView` as each view place in the UI must be constrained to its parent or child in some way

  - https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#add-a-constraint
- If you converted the `ConstraintLayout` to a `RelativeView` or a `LinearLayout`. It is possible the attributes are left in the XML of the constrained attributes within the children views inside your layout.  thos`app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/text_title"`

  - https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-the-new-android-constraintlayout-eed37fe8d8f1

Hope any of this solved your problem!

Comment: <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="367dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="9dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="85dp" />

Comment: Can you please show the code of your whole layout file? Would help understand what exactly it is you're trying to accomplish.